# Proof required for a sufficient condition to find when a positive integer is an absolute pseudoprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The theorem below is from the book “Elementary Number Theory” by “David Burton”

“Let n be a composite square-free integer, say, n = p1 p2 · · · pr , where the pi are distinct primes. If pi−1|n−1 for all i=1,2,...,r, then n is an absolute pseudoprime.”

The proof in the book considers only the case where gcd(a, n) is equal to 1. Can somebody please complete the proof when gcd(a, n) ≠ 1 ?

Comment: What does $a$ stand for?

Comment: Usually, an "absolute pseudoprime"  is a synonym for [Carmichael Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelNumber.html), and the relevant test is for $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$.  If you meant something different, you should explain.  If you mean that $b^n\equiv b\pmod n$ with no assumption on the gcd, then you can deduce that from the relatively prime case.

Comment: I am sorry for all the confusions. Here a is an arbitrary integer. And yes, as I am learning maths, I certainly didn't know about Carmichael numbers. Though I understood your explanation @lulu. Thank you :)

Comment: Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).